# Is it possible to mark a method as explicitly used in C#?

Tags: c#, methods, nunit, warnings

I have a method that is accessed by NUnit only with its name via reflection, and I can't use `nameof()` because this is a TestCaseSource accessing test data in a static method in a derived class (the input data and `[SetUp]` are different for each derived class, but the execution of the test is the same). This method doesn't need to be public/protected for NUnit to work, so for minimizing unwanted access I would like to set it to private, however, if I set it as private then I get a warning that the method is unused.

Is there a way to mark a method as explicitly used? Perhaps an attribute, or a preprocessor directive, that can tell the analyzer that this method is used?

Comment: Disable the warning with a `#pragma warning disable xxxx` and `#pragma warning restore xxxx`  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives#pragma-warning

Comment: The other thing you can do is not use reflection and mark the method as internal, and use `InternalsVisibleToAttribute` which would achieve the same thing I guess :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you can suppress the warning by surrounding the method declaration with [a preprocessor directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives#pragma-warning). I'm assuming the warning you are seeing is [CS0067](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0067). Example:

```cs
#pragma warning disable CS0067
private void MyMethod()
#pragma warning restore CS0067
{
   // Method body
}
```